# O que é um valor opaco?

Tags: terminologia, convenções-de-nome

Por vezes vejo em documentações ou especificações que um determinado valor, no geral, *string*, pode, ou deve, ser considerado opaco. O que isso realmente quer dizer? Quais são as características que definem uma *string* como opaca?

A citar, vale referenciar a [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), também discutida [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228220/o-que-s%C3%A3o-path-parameters-em-uma-uri), que afirma que um *segmento de caminho* é considerado opaco pela sintaxe genérica.

> *[...] a path segment is considered opaque by the generic syntax*

Assim como é válido referenciar a [documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) sobre o atributo `id` que diz que o valor do atributo é uma *string* opaca.

> *This attribute's value is an opaque string*

O significado de opaco nas duas situações é o mesmo? Pois, ainda na documentação MDN há, logo após o trecho citado, a seguinte afirmação:

> *[...] this means that web author must not use it to convey any information*

Que, traduzindo, seria que o autor não deve utilizar o atributo `id` para transmitir qualquer informação. Considerando que o *path* da URL é o identificador de recurso requisitado, é correto afirmar que este também é opaco por não carregar nenhuma informação? Em caso afirmativo, uma URL amigável, que carrega valores de atributos no *path* (por exemplo, `/user/edit/1`), quebram a definição de valor opaco?

Opcional para respostas: citar outros valores que são considerados opacos.

Answer (score 12):

Em ciência da computação, o conceito de opaco é conhecido em 2 momentos, no tipo de dado opaco e nos ponteiros opacos.

Na RFC 3986 o termo opaque é citado 5 vezes dentro de um contexto frasal:

1:

> URI scheme specifications can define *opaque identifiers* by
> disallowing use of slash characters

2:

> after the scheme component delimiter (":") is *considered    opaque* to
> URI processing

3:

> treating it as an *opaque* string from the double-slash to    the first
> terminating delimiter

4:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> *considered opaque* by the generic syntax.

5:

> All references to *"opaque" URIs* have been replaced with a better
> description of how the path component may be opaque to hierarchy.

A RFC 3986 não especifica exatamente qual a terminologia que foi utilizada, veja esse outro [documento](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bishnoi-mpls-mldp-opaque-types-00#section-2)  , ele define uma terminologia . Se o autor da RFC quis representar esse mesmo contexto aplicando-se em conjunto com o termo  `string` ou outro objeto é possível interpretar como se fosse realmente referente à natureza de tipo, já que foi aplicado nessas frases como `adjetivo` e não `substantivo`, no caso uma variável string opaca, ou uma URI(objeto) opaco.

Para entender o tipo opaco precisamos ver seus conceitos aplicados, diferenciar do ponteiro opaco e  definir transparencia.

Um tipo opaco é qualquer tipo cujos detalhes internos não são visíveis para o aplicativo usando o tipo.

> Na ciência da computação, um tipo de dado opaco é um tipo de dado
> cuja estrutura de dados concreta não está definida em uma interface.
> Isso quer dizer, com informações ocultas, já que seus valores só podem
> ser manipulados ao chamar sub-rotinas que tenham acesso às informações
> que faltam.  A representação concreta do tipo está oculta aos usuários
> e a implementação visível está incompleta. Um tipo de dado cuja
> representação é visível é chamado de transparente. Os tipos de dados
> opacos são freqüentemente usados para implementar tipos de dados
> abstratos. [¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type)

Em C, C ++ e Objective-C, você pode dizer ao compilador que um tipo será definido mais tarde usando uma declaração direta [²](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735232/3706998):

```
// declaração direta de um struct em C, C++ and Objective-C
struct Foo;

// declaração direta de class em C++:
class Bar;

// declaração direta de class em Objective-C:
@class Baz;
```

O tipo de dado opaco em geral refere-se a uma estrutura incompleta (que foi declarada mas não definida), como struct Foo;. Não se sabe nada sobre Foo, mas pode-se usá-lo em alguns casos como Foo& e Foo*.
Ref. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477523/3706998)

Os tipos de dados opacos não são os mesmos que os ponteiros opacos, algumas linguagens de programação, como C, permitem a declaração de [ponteiros opacos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) , cujo tamanho e campos estão ocultos do cliente. A única coisa que o cliente pode fazer com um objeto de tal tipo é levar seu endereço de memória, para produzir um ponteiro opaco.

O exemplo mais clássico é o FILE * retornado por `fopen()` da linguagem C. O tipo FILE * não é necessário para ser completo e, portanto, os programas compatíveis e conformes devem tratá-lo como se estivesse incompleto, ou seja, um ponteiro opaco. O padrão de design do ponteiro opaco também é conhecido como  [Pimpl (pointer-to-implementation)(ponteiro para implementação).](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fh = fopen( "foo", "r" );
    if ( fh != NULL )
    {
        fprintf( fh, "Hello" );
        fclose( fh );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Já um valor transparente é usado para onde algo está presente, mas você não pode vê-lo. `Opaque` é usado onde algo está presente, mas você não pode ver dentro dele para inspecionar seu funcionamento interno.[³](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385138/3706998)

*Ref. [Friedman, Daniel P.; Wand, Mitchell, (2008). Essentials of Programming Languages (3rd ed.). MIT Press. p. 34-42. ISBN 978-0-262-06279-4.](https://karczmarczuk.users.greyc.fr/TEACH/Doc/EssProgLan.pdf)*

Pelo método de assimilação podemos tentar entender o que exatamente representa esse valor opaco para o contexto.
No contexto da RFC 3986 faz sentido quando usamos a à definição de tipo opaco (*Opaque datatype*) referenciado acima.

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> *considered opaque* by the generic syntax.

Se trazermos para português e substituir o termo opaco por seu significado no contexto "opaque" da ciência da computação.

> Além de segmentos de pontos em caminhos hierárquicos, um segmento de caminho é > considerado sem uma implementação aparente pela sintaxe genérica.

Levando-se em consideração esses aspectos do tipo opaco, quando foi usado o termo `opaque`, somos levados a acreditar que "string opaque" seria uma valor que está presente mas não foi implementado, ou que não foi definido, está oculto ao implementador, suas definições de tamanho, estrutura e métodos não são aparentes.

Em virtude do que foi mencionado o valor opaco é aquele que não tem uma forma definida ou não declarada, mas que sua estrutura interna existe e é reconhecida pela sintaxe, mas é desconhecida e/ou sem interpretação.

> Considerando que o path da URL é o identificador de recurso
> requisitado, é correto afirmar que este também é opaco por não
> carregar nenhuma informação?

A única certeza que temos é que é possivelmente uma string, mas se atribuirmos ao contexto que defendi acima,  seria correto sim afirmar que é opaco por não revelar detalhes de sua implementação ou estrutura.

Por exemplo numa URI `/user/update/:id+`  poderíamos ter:

```
/user/edit/1
```

e

```
/user/edit/1,2,3,4
```

No primeiro caso teríamos um update de um único recurso, na último o update de múltiplos recursos. A natureza dessa implementação é opaca, sem uma definição visível.

> Em caso afirmativo, uma URL amigável, que
> carrega valores de atributos no path (por exemplo, /user/edit/1),
> quebram a definição de valor opaco?

Não quebraria a definição pois mesmo assim você não está expondo a implementação do valor. Podemos dizer que ainda é um valor opaco.

Comment: Resposta melhorou bastante nessas últimas edições. É possível afirmar, então, que o valor é opaco por não expor características de implementação? Por exemplo, com uma URI eu identifico um recurso no servidor, mas não tenho meios de caracterizar como esse recurso foi implementado - sei qual é a entrada e qual é a saída esperada, mas não como é o processo. E quanto ao atributo `id` no HTML o contexto é o mesmo? Nesse é até mais confuso, pois como é apenas um identificador do elemento no DOM, não consigo imaginar uma situação que pudesse ser considerado transparente.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Tive que estudar mais à noite sobre isso, só que fiquei sem interent e não postei minhas conclusões, só agora. Eu realmente não encontrei referência explicando exatamente sobre "valor opaco", já li muito esse termo em  documentações de orientação à objetos, mas nunca dentro desse contexto da RFC. O que eu tentei fazer foi trazer para o contexto conhecido, o autor não deixou claro se o contexto é realmente esse. Mas eu tenho quase certeza que sim.

Comment: Ao ler a documentação da MDN sobre o atributo  `id` é mais confusa ainda. Ela estabelece que ele não deve ser usado apra transmitir qualquer informação. Porém ele pode ser usado para ser o `location.hash` do javascript, então os navegadores implementam "offsets" de posição para o elemento que carrega id. Não faz muito sentido pra mim também.

Comment: Se eu colocar uma explicação sobre a versão oposta, transparent, ajudaria a elucidar o termo?

Comment: Provavelmente ajudaria.

Comment: Talvez a resposta [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477523/1377664) possa acrescentar algo: _"opaque data type mostly refers to an incomplete struct (one that has been declared but not defined), such as `struct X;`.You know nothing about X, you just can use in some contexts X& and X*."_ Traduzindo: _"tipo de dado opaco em geral refere-se a uma estrutura incompleta (que foi declarada mas não definida), como `struct X;`. Não se sabe nada sobre X, mas pode-se usá-lo em alguns casos como X& e X*."_ A pergunta foi em específico à linguagem C, mas pode dar uma noção geral.