# Como obter todos os arquivos utilizados numa página utilizando o "requests"?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, get, python-requests

Como nós sabemos, ao acessar um site pelo *browser*, vários arquivos como imagens, músicas, scripts, CSS, entre outros, são baixados para serem utilizados dentro de uma página `HTML`.

Utilizando a biblioteca `requests`, é possível utilizar a função `get` para solicitar a página, porém ele não recebe outros arquivos ou pelo menos os links para baixar esses outros arquivos. Logo, se eu quiser salvar uma página no meu computador, ela estaria incompleta, exemplo:

**Página html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste de JavaScript</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="caozinho.png" alt="Cachorrinho">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código Python para salvar a página:**

```
import requests

url = "https://meuSite.com/"
response = requests.get(url)

with open("página.html","wb") as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

**Resultado final:**

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Há alguma forma de obter todos arquivos de uma requisição utilizando o `requests` ?

Comment: O conceito de listar diretório não está presente no [protocolo HTTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). A exitencia desse tipo de listagem vai depender se o servidor está ou não configurado para exibir um HTML com a estrutura de pasta e a semântica em que é construído esse HTML.

Comment: Apenas o Requests não, mas pode utilizá-lo no processo. A solução do seu problema é pegar o conteúdo de `response.content`, que é o HTML da página, analisar o código extraindo todos os elementos que deseja e capturando suas respectivas URLs. Por exemplo, você pode buscar todos os elementos `<img>` e extrair o valor do atributo `src` para assim listar todos as URLs das imagens na página. A partir das URLS bara fazer uma nova requisição para baixá-las uma a uma, exatamente como o navegador faz.

Comment: Mas lembre-se que a URL é, por definição, um [valor opaco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232958/5878). Isso significa que a sua cópia do site pode não ser fiel à estrutura original, apenas reproduzir o mesmo resultado (visual).

Comment: Obrigado @Woss <3