# Redirecionamento de pagina com mensagem de erro

Tags: php, html, redirecionamento

Boa tarde estou com uma duvida
este comando está correto?

`http://localhost/site/index.php#contato?info=Email%20Vazio`

> index.php#contato?info=Email%20Vazio

Esta é a função que envia o comando porem a pagina fica no topo e não aparece mais a mensagem no formulário.

```
private function setNome($nome){
    if(!empty($nome)){
    $validar = new Validar($nome);
    $this->nome = $validar->getValidado();
    }else{
    $this->setError("Nome Vazio");
    return print "<script language='JavaScript'>location.href='"
    . "index.php#contato?info={$this->getError()}'</script>";
    exit();
    }
```

Caso eu retire o `#contato`, funciona mas eu gostaria que fosse direto para o formulário para que o usuário não tivesse que descer a pagina toda novamente a cada erro de digitação

Comment: É o contrário: primeiro vem a query para depois o fragment; veja o formato nessa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228220/64969

Comment: A âncora #contato deve vir depois dos parâmetros. Teste assim: `http://localhost/site/index.php?info=Email%20Vazio#contato`

Comment: deu certo obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Adriano! usa a função header() do php, com ela você faz esse redirecionamento.

Ex:

Header(location: 'www.google.com.br');