# Gostaria de saber o conceito de QueryString , o que é ? , para que serve ?. Estou em uma aula sobre flask e me foi apresentado sobre QueryString

Tags: python, string, flask, querystring

```js
@app.route('/novo') #novo.html
def novo():
    if 'usuario_logado' not in session or session['usuario_logado'] == None:
            return redirect('/loguin?proxima=novo')
    return render_template('novo.html', titulo='Novo Jogo')
```

**return redirect('/loguin?proxima=novo')**

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que são Path Parameters em uma URI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228220/o-que-s%c3%a3o-path-parameters-em-uma-uri)

Comment: [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/232298/95771) fala mais sobre as Query Strings